# How to set the width of one element to the width of another in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a box view to underline some text in Xamarin and I want to set the width of the box view to the width of the label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define WidthRequest for the Label and bind that to the Box view as shown below.

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button x:Name="BtnSend" Clicked="BtnSend_Clicked" Text="Send" WidthRequest="150" />

    <Label Text="Hello" BackgroundColor="Yellow" WidthRequest="{Binding WidthRequest, Source={x:Reference BtnSend}}"  />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Label has a property ***TextDecorations***. You can set it to ***Underline*** to underline a text without using BoxView.

```
    <Label Text="Your Text" TextDecorations="Underline">
```

Comment: Why is this not the answer? if you're trying to simply underline text, then use ```TextDecorations```. The accepted answer does answer the question correctly, but it is not the best way to underline text.

Comment: @ottermatic because i needed the underline to be a different colour to the text